SQL/Spark/Polars Join tables that might have a match on different columns
I have two tables with columns containing the same information (e.g. company_name, address, zipcode), but there some caveats:

in one of the two tables, one of the information can be missing (either company_name or address or zip)
the same company can have different name formats (e.g. Apple, Apple Inc)
the same company can have a different address format (e.g. 123 Street and Inside Mall X)

So far I have tried to:

merge the two datasets
left join the new dataset with itself on all the columns by finding the first available match (with Polars, the join is on [pl.coalesce('company_name', 'address', 'zipcode')]

After this, I thought of selecting the original columns with a condition to fetch the first available value between the original columns and the joined column.
I need to find a way to address point 2 and 3, but what I am really looking for is some understanding on how to approach the join in the context of point 1. Do you have any tip?
I can use either plain SQL or Spark or Polars.
Thanks a lot!

What are you expecting should be the behavior if there are two different Apple stores in the same zip code with different company_name and address values? This seems to be a problem which requires cleaning and mapping your datasets to common values before trying to join.

@JesusDiazRivero thanks for the reply. Do you know of any quick way to determine a common value? I can think of some NLP techniques, but that would take the column with all the ‘dirty’ values out of the table and work on that, but that would probably kill the performance if the datasets were to increase in size considerably
